# Set HomePage Js is not working in IE11

Tags: javascript

I've tried to use a JavaScript to set a link as homepage but its not working in Internet explorer 11

```
<input type="button" value="Make This Site Your Home Page" onClick="this.style.behavior='url(#default#homepage)'; this.setHomePage('http://microsoft.com');">
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="button" onClick="sethomepage()" />
```

js

```
function sethomepage(){
  location.href = "http://microsoft.com";
}
```